# React Native Error: Payload cannot exceed 104857600 bytes

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

Just recently when working with react native and metro as bundler I've been getting this error whenever the app refreshes on the IOS Simulator, causing the app to disconnect from Metro.

Full Stack trace:

```
error: A WebSocket client got a connection error. Please reload your device to get HMR working again: Error: payload cannot exceed 104857600 bytes
at Receiver.error (/Users/zebras/Repos/provotum/voter_app_2/node_modules/metro/node_modules/ws/lib/Receiver.js:321:18)
at Receiver.maxPayloadExceeded (/Users/zebras/Repos/provotum/voter_app_2/node_modules/metro/node_modules/ws/lib/Receiver.js:389:8)
at Receiver.<anonymous> (/Users/zebras/Repos/provotum/voter_app_2/node_modules/metro/node_modules/ws/lib/Receiver.js:479:20)
at Receiver.add (/Users/zebras/Repos/provotum/voter_app_2/node_modules/metro/node_modules/ws/lib/Receiver.js:103:24)
at Socket.realHandler (/Users/zebras/Repos/provotum/voter_app_2/node_modules/metro/node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocket.js:825:20)
at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:309:12)
at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:284:9)
at Socket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:223:10)
at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23)
```

I could not really find anything relevant through google and am to unexperienced with RN to make anything from this message myself. I tried re-producing the steps that I *think* where the last I took before the error occurred, which was:

Creating a new component (`Intro`), registering the component with the Navigation:

```
<NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen

                name="Login"
                component={Login}
                options={{ title: 'something', name: 'Login' }}
            />
            <Stack.Screen name="list" component={List} />
            <Stack.Screen name="intro" component={Intro} />
```

And creating the template of the component before implementing it:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { PageControlView } from 'react-native-ios-kit';
import { Title1, Title3, Body, Button } from 'react-native-ios-kit';
import { View } from 'react-native';
const styles = require('../style');

const Intro = ({ navigation, route, props }) => {
return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <PageControlView defaultPage={1}>
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Title1>First page.</Title1>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Title1>Second page.</Title1>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Title1>Third page.</Title1>
            </View>
        </PageControlView>
    </View>

)
};

export default Intro;
```

Edit: however removing the new component did not change anything.

Comment: Have you found anything yet with this? I'm literally having the same issue right now...